# How to keep cursor in view in jetpack compose TextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-textfield

I am working on a jetpack compose notes app. I used two textfield inside a column but the cursor keeps going behind the keyboard. I also checked official android architecture example apps. They also used some hack to keep the cursor in view.

Is there any solution.

Video: https://imgur.com/a/LCLwe7p
Github: https://github.com/laraib07/zenote/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/laraib07/zenote/ui/screen/add_edit/AddEditNote.kt

The cursor must remain on screen.